# Get the Query parameter from the URL in to Component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am trying to understand how I can get the Query parameter from the URl in to my Component. Below is what I tried, I set the route in the `app-routing.module.ts` like

```
  {
      path: 'ProjectShipment/userId/231',
      component: ProjectShipmentComponent,
      data: { title: 'Project Shipment' },
  }
```

And with in the `project-shipment.component.ts` I tried like

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
export class ProjectShipmentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const userId = params['userId'];
      console.log(userId);
    });}}
```

When I debug it I get undefined in the logs

[image]

What am I missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your route to

```
{
      path: 'ProjectShipment/:userId',
      component: ProjectShipmentComponent,
      data: { title: 'Project Shipment' },
  }
```

Then when you call it like `yourhost/projectshipment/231` in your component

```
 this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      const userId = params['userId'];
      console.log(userId);
    })
```

to get queryparams you code is right but your route should

```
{
      path: 'ProjectShipment',
      component: ProjectShipmentComponent,
      data: { title: 'Project Shipment' },
  }
```

and url should be `yourhost/projectshipment?userid=231`